# Non Measurability of evaluation map involving cylindrical $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $\Omega$ be the set of all functions $w:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ with the minimal $\sigma$ algebra $B$ containing all cylindrical subsets. I have to prove that the evaluation mapping $S:\Omega \times \mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $S(w,t)=w(t)$ is not measurable. I already proved that bounded functions and continuous functions are not measurable subsets of $(\Omega, B)$.

Also I proved that if $C>0$, $\{q_n\}$ is some enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $S$ is measurable then the set $$T=\{w\in \Omega : |w(t)|<C \mbox{ for all } t\in \mathbb{Q}\}=\bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}}T_{q_{n}}$$ where $T_{q_{n}}=\{w\in\Omega: (w,q_n )\in S^{-1}((-C,C))\}$ must be measurable because of the measurability of the sections $T_{q_n}$. But after this I'm stucked, does anyone has some hint for finishing the proof? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the following fact: if a set is measurable with respect to a product $\sigma$-algebra then every horizontal and vertical section of the set is measurable.

Let $V \subset \mathbb{R}$ be a non-measurable set, and take $w = 1_V$.  Then the vertical section at $w$ of $S^{-1}(\{1\})$ equals $V$.